# CheckBox value, I want to add ,if user check the checkBox then it should add amount=amount + 18% , if not then only amount my Code

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I want to add, if the user checks the checkBox then it should add `amount=amount + 18%`, if not then the only amount
 my Code

```
final amountController = TextEditingController();

Container(
  height: 50.0,
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
  decoration:
      BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[300], width: 1)),
  child: TextFormField(
    controller: amountController,
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
      border: InputBorder.none,
      hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]),
      hintText: "Assesment Amount",
      fillColor: Colors.transparent,
    ),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  ),
);
```

//=======checkBox code============

```
Container(
  child: Checkbox(
      value: checkBoxValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          checkBoxValue = value;
        });
      }),
);
```

//========Insert button Code=========

```
else if (update == false && imageFile != null) {
  setState(() {
    name = titleController.text;
    nameList.add(name);
    amountList.add(amountController.text);
    img.add(imageFile);
    titleController.clear();
    amountController.clear();
    imageFile = null;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all we will parse written amount which is in String to integer so we can perform calculations then we can get status of checkbox using boolean checkBoxValue. If checkBoxValue == true we will add 18 % of amount entered into amount variable else we will just add amount as it is.

```
else if (update == false && imageFile != null) {
      setState(() {
      name = titleController.text;
      nameList.add(name);
      int _amount = int.parse(amountController.text);
      _amount = checkBoxValue ? _amount + ((18 / _amount) * 100) : _amount;
      amountList.add(_amount);
      img.add(imageFile);
      titleController.clear();
      amountController.clear();
      imageFile = null;
      });
}
```

Comment: amount=checkBoxValue ? amount + (amount*(18/100)) : amount;

Answer (score 0):

```
int amount=0;
if (checkBoxValue){
    amount = int.parse(amountController.text) + int.parse(amountController.text)*18/100;
}
else {
    amount = int.parse(amountController.text);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.